# Radio button to check all boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table class="table borderless">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>+/-</th>
        <th>Searches</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="optradio" class="custom"> ALL</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="optradio" class="custom"> ALL</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="optradio" class="custom"> ALL</td>
        <td><input id="ex2" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,1000]" data-slider-id="RC" id="R"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector"> Rank 1-10</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" > Up</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" > Over</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector"> Rank 11-20</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" > Down</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" > Under</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector"> Rank 21-100</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" > No movement</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="custom-selector"> Not in top 100</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $(".custom").change(function () {
              $(".custom").parent().find(".custom-selector").prop("checked", true);
       })
   });
```

What I need is a radio button that checks all the boxes when selected.

Right now nothing happens when I click the radio button. However, if I add this radio button:

```
<input type="radio" id="op5" value="1" name="options2" class="custom">
```

Then they both work. Even the initial one checks all the boxes.

What is this strange behavior? I'm missing something

EDIT: it appears the radio button must be outside the table? Can I have it inside somehow?

Comment: Why you do not add a class for a table. For example, class="table borderless ranks". Then you can select checboxes simpler `$(.ranks .custom-selector').

Comment: y not you go for diff class name for rank,postion,search

Comment: is there any reason You using radio button for select all, My idea will be go for checkbox..

Comment: I thought it would be more intuitive for the users? being different than the checkboxes I guess

Comment: ok then what about deselect all checkbox concept. In this there is deselect all task?

Comment: No, if you check out the boxes, it seems like the radio button stays filled, can I make it go unfilled when not everything is checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
$(".custom").closest("tbody").find(".custom-selector").prop("checked", true);
```

or Just:

```
$(".custom-selector").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".custom").change(function () {
    $(this).parents('tbody').find(".custom-selector:checked");
});
```

and some reference: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector

eventually remove your action selector using `.not(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".custom").change(function () {
             $(".custom-selector").prop("checked", true);
        })
    });
```